# SNMP custom made device ESP8266

Tags: networking, udp, snmp, esp8266

my company uses the application PRTG from paessler.com to monitor several SNMP sensors, I need to monitor the voltage of some devices and transmit it to the manager.

I was going to use an ESP8266 programmed via arduino to do it.
So far I've been able to send data to the ESP via UDP, and I configured it in the manager so it can retrieve the information from it and ping it.

The ping tests are successful however the monitoring does not work, by using the serial interface I can see that the ESP is receiving the data from the manager, with the OID that was set up. But the monitor shows it as inactive, I set up the ESP to send a simple string in the response.

When using a program called Packet Sender I am able to send the udp packets and receive the response as well, and everything works fine.

The ports I am using is 161 to receive in the ESP and I made it send to the 161, 123, 1023 as i saw specified in the prtg site

I may be sending the packets trough a port that is not the right one, or maybe I have to put a header before the message so the controller can Interpret it. I am not sure what the error can be. Any help will be apreciated

Comment: I am having a hard time following you, sorry. You are trying to use the ESP 8266 as the SNMP manager? You are communicating with a Windows PC?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough. There is a web controller of SNMP devices (sensors), I want to create an SNMP sensor with the ESP8266, but have not found anything useful so far

Comment: Without code it's impossible to tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty easy - simply use the http push sensor from PRTG:
https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/http_push_data_sensor

All best

Christian

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.